# How to store chars into an array using pointers and malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

My problem now is that I have taken space for different words,but I'm having problems storing this as an array. Even though there are some similar posts like this, nothing seems to work for me and I'm completely stuck here. I want to keep this format(i don't want to change the definition of the function). Grateful for all help and comments!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int i, len = 0, counter = 0;
char ** p = 0;

for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
    len++;

    if(s[i] == ' ' || s[i+1] == '\0'){

        counter ++;
 for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    p[i] = s[i];
    }

}
printf("%d\n", len);
printf("%d\n", counter);
return p; 
}

int main() {
char *s = "This is a string";
int n;
int i;



for(i = 0; i < n*; i++){
 //also not sure how to print this 
}
}
```

Comment: You could consider `p` to be an array of pointers. Therefore e.g. `p[i]` is a pointer, and doing `p[i] = s[i]` is wrong since `s[i]` is not a pointer. Also, you should not use the same index for both `p` and `s`, since the next element to assign to in `p` will most likely not be the same as the index of the current character in `s`. And don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*, so unless you want to modify the original string (like [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) does) then you need to duplicate part of the source

Comment: There are also many other things wrong with your current code, like you allocating memory and reassigning to `p` multiple times, losing the previously allocated memory. I suggest you sit down with a piece of paper, write down your requirements, and then analyze the requirements in detail to figure out a design that you could turn into a working implementation.

Comment: your code has typos and does not compile. Try compiling with `-Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -Wsign-conversion -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wunintialized -Wextra`

Comment: you are passing `n` and never using `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code and it's now working correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(const char* s, int *n);
char** split(const char* s, int *n) {
    int i, len = 0, counter = 0;
    char ** p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; ; ++i) {
        if(s[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    ++counter;

    p = (char **) malloc(counter * sizeof(char*));

    for(int i = 0, c = 0; ; ++i, ++c) {
        if(s[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        len = 0;
        while(s[len + i + 1] != ' ' && s[len + i + 1] != '\0') {
            ++len;
        }
        p[c] = (char *) malloc(len * sizeof(char) + 1);
        int k = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < i + len + 1; ++j) {
            p[c][k++] = s[j];
        }
        p[c][k] = '\0';
        i += len + 1;
    }
    *n = counter;
    return p;
}

int main() {
    char *s = "This is a string";
    int n;
    int i;
    char** split_s = split(s, &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", split_s[i]);
    }
}
```

But I suggest you do a little bit clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using sscanf. scanf and sscanf considers space as an end of input. I have taken benefit of that to make it work for you.

```
char *str = (char*) "This is a string";
char buffer[50];
char ** p = (char**)malloc(1 * sizeof(*p));
for (int i = 0; str[0] != NULL; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        p = (char**)realloc(p, i * sizeof(p));
    }

    sscanf(str, "%s", buffer);
    int read = strlen(buffer);
    str += read + 1;                

    p[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*read + 1);
    strcpy(p[i], buffer);
    printf("%s\n", p[i]);
}
```

Since this pointer is growing in both the dimensions, every time a new string is found we need to resize the `p` itself and then the new address that it contains should be resized too .

Answer (score 0):

*My problem now is that I have taken space for different words using malloc, but I'm having problems storing this as an array.*

When *addressable* memory for a collection of strings is needed, then a collection of pointers, as well as memory for each pointer needed.

In your code:

```
p = (char**)malloc(counter*sizeof(char*));
```

You have created the collection of pointers, but you have not yet created memory at those locations to accommodate the strings.  (By the way, the cast is not necessary)

Here are the essential steps to both create a collection of pointers, and memory for each:

```
//for illustration, pick sizes for count of strings needed,
//and length of longest string needed.
#define NUM_STRINGS 5
#define STR_LEN     80

char **stringArray = NULL;

stringArray = malloc(NUM_STRINGS*sizeof(char *));// create collection of pointers
if(stringArray)
{
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_STRINGS;i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = malloc(STR_LEN + 1);//create memory for each string
        if(!stringArray[i])                  //+1 room for nul terminator
        {
            //handle error
        }
    }
}
```

As a function it could look like this:  (replacing malloc with calloc for initialized space)

```
char ** Create2DStr(size_t numStrings, size_t maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    char **a = {0};
    a = calloc(numStrings, sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(maxStrLen + 1, 1);
    }
    return a;
}
```

using this in your `split()` function:

```
char** split(const char* s, int *n){

    int i, len = 0, counter = 0, lenLongest = 0
    char ** p = 0;

    //code to count words and longest word

    p = Create2DStr(counter, longest + 1); //+1 for nul termination
    if(p)
    {
        //your searching code
        //...
        // when finished, free memory
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start at the logic.

How does a string like `A quick brown fox.` get processed?  I would suggest:

1. Count the number of words, and the amount of memory needed to store the words. (In C, each string ends with a terminating nul byte, `\0`.)
2. Allocate enough memory for the pointers and the words.
3. Copy each word from the source string.

We have a string as an input, and we want an array of strings as output.  The simplest option is

```
char **split_words(const char *source);
```

where the return value is `NULL` if an error occurs, or an array of pointers terminated by a `NULL` pointer otherwise.  All of it is dynamically allocated at once, so calling `free()` on the return value will free both the pointers and their contents.

Let's start implementing the logic according to the bullet points above.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char **split_words(const char *source)
{
    size_t      num_chars = 0;
    size_t      num_words = 0;
    size_t      w = 0;
    const char *src;
    char      **word, *data;

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (!source)
        return NULL;  /* split_words(NULL) will return NULL. */

    /* Count the number of words in source (num_words),
       and the number of chars needed to store
       a copy of each word (num_chars). */
    src = source;
    while (1) {

        /* Skip any leading whitespace (not just spaces). */
        while (*src == '\t' || *src == '\n' || *src == '\v' ||
               *src == '\f' || *src == '\r' || *src == ' ')
            src++;

        /* No more words? */
        if (*src == '\0')
            break;

        /* We have one more word. Account for the pointer itself,
           and the string-terminating nul char. */
        num_words++;
        num_chars++;

        /* Count and skip the characters in this word. */
        while (*src != '\0' && *src != '\t' && *src != '\n' &&
               *src != '\v' && *src != '\f' && *src != '\r' &&
               *src != ' ') {
            src++;
            num_chars++;
        }
    }

    /* If the string has no words in it, return NULL. */
    if (num_chars < 1)
        return NULL;

    /* Allocate memory for both the pointers and the data.
       One extra pointer is needed for the array-terminating
       NULL pointer. */
    word = malloc((num_words + 1) * sizeof (char *) + num_chars);
    if (!word)
        return NULL; /* Not enough memory. */

    /* Since 'word' is the return value, and we use
       num_words + 1 pointers in it, the rest of the memory
       we allocated we use for the string contents. */
    data = (char *)(word + num_words + 1);

    /* Now we must repeat the first loop, exactly,
       but also copy the data as we do so. */
    src = source;
    while (1) {

        /* Skip any leading whitespace (not just spaces). */
        while (*src == '\t' || *src == '\n' || *src == '\v' ||
               *src == '\f' || *src == '\r' || *src == ' ')
            src++;

        /* No more words? */
        if (*src == '\0')
            break;

        /* We have one more word. Assign the pointer. */
        word[w] = data;
        w++;

        /* Count and skip the characters in this word. */
        while (*src != '\0' && *src != '\t' && *src != '\n' &&
               *src != '\v' && *src != '\f' && *src != '\r' &&
               *src != ' ') {
            *(data++) = *(src++);
        }

        /* Terminate this word. */
        *(data++) = '\0';
    }

    /* Terminate the word array. */
    word[w] = NULL;

    /* All done! */
    return word;
}
```

We can test the above with a small test `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char  **all;
    size_t  i;

    all = split_words(" foo Bar. BAZ!\tWoohoo\n More");
    if (!all) {
        fprintf(stderr, "split_words() failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; all[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("all[%zu] = \"%s\"\n", i, all[i]);

    free(all);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If we compile and run the above, we get

```
all[0] = "foo"
all[1] = "Bar."
all[2] = "BAZ!"
all[3] = "Woohoo"
all[4] = "More"
```

The downside of this approach (of using one `malloc()` call to allocate memory for both the pointers and the data), is that we cannot easily grow the array; we can really just treat it as one big clump.

---

A better approach, especially if we intend to add new words dynamically, is to use a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t   max_words;  /* Number of pointers allocated */
    size_t   num_words;  /* Number of words in array */
    char   **word;       /* Array of pointers */
} wordarray;
```

Unfortunately, this time we need to allocate each word separately. However, if we use a structure to describe each word in a common allocation buffer, say

```
typedef struct {
    size_t   offset;
    size_t   length;
} wordref;

typedef struct {
    size_t   max_words;
    size_t   num_words;
    wordref *word;
    size_t   max_data;
    size_t   num_data;
    char    *data;
} wordarray;
#define  WORDARRAY_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL }

static inline const char *wordarray_word_ptr(wordarray *wa, size_t i)
{
    if (wa && i < wa->num_words)
        return wa->data + wa->word[i].offset;
    else
        return "";
}

static inline size_t wordarray_word_len(wordarray *wa, size_t i)
{
    if (wa && i < wa->num_words)
        return wa->word[i].length;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The idea is that if you declare

```
wordarray  words = WORDARRAY_INIT;
```

you can use `wordarray_word_ptr(&words, i)` to get a pointer to the `i`th word, or a pointer to an empty string if `i`th word does not exist yet, and `wordarray_word_len(&words, i)` to get the length of that word (much faster than calling `strlen(wordarray_word_ptr(&words, i))`).

The underlying reason why we cannot use `char *` here, is that `realloc()`ing the data area (where the word pointers would point to) may change its address. If that were to happen, we'd have to adjust every pointer in our array.  It is much easier to use offsets to the data area instead.

The only downside to this approach is that deleting words does not mean a corresponding shrinkage in the data area.  However, it is possible to write a simple "compactor" function, that repacks the data to a new area, so that holes left by deleted words are "moved" to the end of the data area.  Usually, this is not necessary, but you might wish to add a member to the `wordarray` structure, say the number of lost characters from word deletions, so that the compaction can be done heuristically the next time the data area would be otherwise resized.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for a fantastic explanation, it really helped and I understand very well now!